# Excel like javascript editing in RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**What i have:** A table generated by single cells of values like:

```
<tr>
  <%= render :partial => 'partials/fieldtypes/show_in_table', :locals => {:fieldtype => 'textline', :data => {'object' => object, 'value' => 'name'}, :vars => {'textline' => object.name}} %>
  <%= render :partial...
</tr>
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<td class='tablecell' <% data.each do |dat| %>data-<%= raw(dat[0]) %>='<%= raw(dat[1]) %>' <% end %> >
  <%= render :partial => 'partials/fieldtypes/show/'+fieldtype, :locals => {:vars => vars} %>
</td>
```

Now i want to edit single entries/cells of that table like in MS Excel by doubleclicking on them.
The site is running on full javascript, so pages are not being linked.

**So what i want is:** Generating (**not prerendering and switching visibility!**) a form everytime the user wants to edit a field (by doubleclicking).

**My ideas so far:** As you can see i was trying to store all the necessary data in html5 data-tags to generate the form. The plan was to call a controller action everytime a cell is doubleclicked and to generate the form with the database connection with rails.

**Problem/Question:** Does this work that way? Because the data in the tags looks converted and useless for further interaction. And if it works: How do i create a controller action for that with a proper route?

Or are there any easier solutions? As stated i do not want to render the form hidden directly!

Comment: Calling a controller action every time a cell is double-clicked sounds like it could using make your site painful for people with any significant lag on their Internet connection. I would suggest implementing the desired functionality purely in Javascript (perhaps using JQuery, etc). Catching a double-click event on a DOM element and then dynamically creating a text field sounds like it should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: @AlexD how can i generate a form dynamically with jQuery? If i have a dynamic select field i need to connect to the database before generating the form, else the available options will only update on refreshing the page. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I would preload the data into a JS array/hash when the page is first loaded, then dynamically generate forms using that. I don't know jQuery well, but in JS you can easily build a HTML string and add it as a new DOM node under a given <div>. I'm sure jQuery has a method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check this gem out it is exactly what you want to do
https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place